# If $A\leq_m^\mathsf{}B$ and $B$ is a regular language, does that imply that $A$ is a regular language?

Tags: turing-machines, np-complete, polynomial-time, polynomial-time-reductions

**Corollary:1** We know that if $A\leq_m^\mathsf{}B$ and $B$ is decidable then $A$ is also decidable.

This is because if there exists a specific algorithm for solving $B$ and we can also reduce $A$ to $B$ then we can have a solution of $A$ as well. Hence $A$ is decidable.

We know that regular languages is always decidable.

**Corollary:2** So from (**Corollary:1**)if $A\leq_m^\mathsf{}B$ and $B$ is regular then $A$ is should also be regular.

But I have made this  wrong my taking Counterexample.
For example, define the languages
$A = \{ 0^n1^n \mid n\ge 0 \} $
and $B = \{1\}$
both over the alphabet $\sum = \{0, 1\}.$
Define the function $f : \sum^*\to \sum^*$ as
$$ f(x) := \begin{cases} 1,&  
\text{if}\ w\in A,\\0,&\text{if}\ w\not\in A\end{cases} $$
Observe that $A$ is a context-free language, so it is also Turing-decidable. Thus, $f$ is a
computable function. Also, $w \in A$ if and only if $f(w) = 1,$ which is true if and only
if $f(w)\in B.$ Hence,$A\leq_m^\mathsf{}B.$ Language $A$ is nonregular, but $B$ is regular since it is finite.

Above example proving that $A$ isn't necessarily regular. But according to
**Corollary:1**,  $A$ must be regular.
I don't understand where I did make mistake during  understanding of theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Corollary $2$ is false.

It seems that you are using the implication "$L$ is regular $\implies$ $L$ is decidable" in the wrong direction. If $A \le_m B$  and $B$ is regular, Corollary 1 only tells you that $A$ is decidable, which does not imply that $A$ is regular.